# Populate HTML Select options based on other HTML Select

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, callback, sidebar

### Goal:

In a sidebar, display two `<select>` options for a form.  The second `<select>` is dependent on the choice of the first.  The second `<select>` will call the appropriate array from Google Apps Script.

### Problem:

I cannot get the array to populate using eventlistener, by attempting `google.run`, or by referring to another function.

### Example:

Below I have three `<select>` fields.  The first is the primary.  The second is a traditional array that is dependent on the first.  The third `<select>` is where I cannot get the pulled arrays from the Apps Script server-side code.  Keep in mind, I'm trying to pull different arrays based off of the 1st `<select>`.

```js
//Google Apps Script
function Array1() {
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('perTwo').getValues();
  Logger.log(rng);
  return rng;
}

function getValuesForRngActive(students_active) {
  var rngValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('students_active').getValues();
  return rngValues.sort();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Entry Selection</h2>
<hr> Period:
<select id="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2'); populate2('slct3')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Per 1</option>
    <option value="2">Per 2</option>
    <option value="3">Per 3</option>
</select>

<hr> Student:
<select id="slct2" onchange="myFunction()"></select>

<hr> New Dependent:
<select id="slct3"></select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
<p id="demo"></p> 
</body>

<script>
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  
  if(s1.value == "1") {
    var optionArray = ["i10", "i20", "Verna"];
  }
  else if (s1.value == "2") {
    var optionArray = ["Last2, First2", "Student, Ima", ""];
  }
  else if (s1.value == "3") {
    var optionArray = ["i10", "i20", "Verna"];
  }
    
  for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = optionArray[i];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i];
    s2.appendChild(newOption);
  }
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("slct2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}

function populate2(s3) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById('slct1');
  var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
  s3.innerHTML = "";
  
  if(s1.value == "1") {
    var optionArray =  google.script.run.Array1();
  }
  else if (s1.value == "2") {
    var optionArray = ["Last2, First2", "Student, Ima", ""];
  }
  else if (s1.value == "3") {
    var optionArray =  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValuesForRngActive('students_active');
  }
    
  for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = optionArray[i];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i];
    s3.appendChild(newOption);
  }
}
</script>

<script>
  // Using the "load" event to execute the function "populate"
  window.addEventListener('load', populate2);
</script>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a function named `onSuccess`  You have added a success handler method:  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)`

Comment: Please review (they have examples too!) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: The developer examples are too vague for me and the attempt to reference the same  ID with different arrays from a previous condition.  Truly stumped, but I'm also a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that App Script function should take the name of the range as parameter:

```
function getValuesForRange(rangeName) {
    var rngValues = SpreadsheetApp
      .getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getRangeByName(rangeName)
      .getValues();
    return rngValues.sort();
}
```

so that the range-name `students_active` can be passed into the App Script function

... and it's success handler callback probably should be `populateSelectA()`.

```
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(populateSelectA)
  .getValuesForRange('students_active');
```

there are a few more issues with the above code ...

while this at least would enable you to populate one `<select>` with `<option>`s.

the misconception somehow is, that these callback functions only accept a single parameter, while your `populate()` accepts two ...App Script should return `{}` or `[]`; with JS function declarations alike `function populateSelectA(data) {}` & `function populateSelectB(data) {}`. jQuery can also be used for the client-side scripting there.